# Real Analysis: Show that, if P* is a refinement of P, then ||P ∗ || ≤ ||P||.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose P = {x<sub>0</sub>, x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>} is a partition of the interval [a, b]. 
Define the mesh of P, denoted ||P|| to be the length of the longest partition interval defined by 
$$
P : \|P\| = \max\{x_i-x_{i-1}: i=1,2,\ldots,n\}
$$

P: ||P|| = max{x<sub>*i*</sub> − x<sub>*i−1*</sub>. : i = 1, 2, ..., n}. 

1. Show that, if P* is a refinement of P, then ||P*|| ≤ ||P||. 
2. Is the converse true? Justify your answer.


My attempt at the first part of the question: 
Suppose P = {x<sub>0</sub>, x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>} is a partition of the interval [a, b]. 
By the Refinement Lemma, we know that L(*f*,P) ≤ L(*f*,P*) and U(*f*,P*) ≤ U(*f*,P). We know that L(*f*,P*) and U(*f*,P*)  are sums of the lengths of each of the partition intervals of P*. Given the lemma, U,L of P* are inbetween U,L of P. This means that every partition of P* is less than P as U and L are sums of each interval in P and P*. Thus ||P*|| ⩽ ||P|| must be true.


I think I'm having the most trouble grasping the definition of a partition and it's refinement. I'm basing my assumption that a refinement P* has to share the same partition points [x<sub>i-1</sub>, x<sub>i</sub>] as P.
Please help guide me towards a solution! Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(You don't need to use $L(f,P)$ and $U(f,P)$ for this problem.  It doesn't involve the function $f$.)

For part 1, note that each subinterval of $P^*$ is contained in a subinterval of $P$, so none of $P^*$'s subintervals can be larger than $\|P\|$.

Part 2.  Hint: the converse is false.

It might help you grasp the definitions of *partition* and *refinement* by drawing out a picture.

A simple example: Let's look at the interval $[0,1]$.  One possible partition is $P = \{0,0.2,0.8,1\}$.  It divides the interval $[0,1]$ into 3 subintervals. The mesh is $\|P\| = 0.6$, because that is the length of the largest subinterval $[0.2,0.8]$. A refinement $P^*$ is a partition that includes these points of $P$ plus some extra, like
$$P^* =\{0,0.2,0.7,0.8,1\}$$
where we just added the point $0.7$.  The mesh of $P^*$ is $\|P^*\| = 0.5 < 0.6$.